Our Email Notifications for our Google Form are not working when we need a PDF File Name for our PDF Attachment in the Email Notification
We have a google request form where we are using an add on "Email Notifications for Google Forms." When we go to customize the file name of the PDF that should be shared with us via email once someone submits a form, (in this case we want the file name to be "REQUEST - {{Project Name}}" it does not properly pull in the project name like we have on our form and it just shows in our email as "REQUEST - ". Any help will be appreciated!!!
Selecting "Project Name" from the dropdown so that the PDF would be named whatever project the requester entered. This did not work when requests were submitted.

The ability to Change PDF File Name is a premium feature of the Email Notifications for Google Forms add-on. Are you using the "Premium" version of the add-on?
